# How to make sure resque background jobs are always up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, resque, rails-activejob

I use ActiveJob with a resque back-end and use capistrano-resque to (re)start my work processes on deploy.

What I have been strugling with is making sure those processes are always up. Can and could such a process crash? Should I put safeguards in making sure that my background jobs always get picked up by a worker?

I have searched far and wide but have not found any standard solution to this.

Comment: You can use [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). Here is a sample script for [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/monit/resque.monit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [god](http://godrb.com/) with resque. Here's an example [script](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/examples/god/resque.god) for it.

#### Capistrano

```
desc "Restart resque workers"
task :restart_workers, roles: :resque do
  run "sudo god restart resque-production"
end

after 'deploy:restart', 'deploy:restart_workers'
```

where `resque-production` is the `w.name` from the script example.

Comment: God does not seem to be alive (judging from its github repo)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it seems like it. Nontheless it works flawlessly. I'm using it for a very long time now.

Comment: Do you domehow integrate god with capistrano to restart the workers on deploy?

Comment: @Honza Updated the answer with Capistrano howto.